# Drupal site folder naming scheme

Tags: drupal

When naming a sites folder in Drupal using a multi-site setup, can I name the site "mydomain" or does it have to be in the format of the domain name like "mydomain.com".
Is there a way to do this using symbolic link in linux?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Drupal matches the domain name requested via HTTP with the folder name inside sites. If it does not match anything it will fall back to "default". So you need to name the folder mydomain.com.

You can definitely use a symbolic link from mydomain.com -> mydomain provided your Apache (or other HTTPd) is configured to resolve symlinks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply GSP.
Just to confirm. So even with symbolic links it won't be possible, correct? Not even with .htaccess file settings either?

Comment: Where do I create the symbolic link? Can it be anywhere on the server or does it need to be in /home/drupal/sites? So would I write ln -s mydomain.com /home/drupal/mydomain.

Comment: Unless your Apache is set to restrict the accessible directories you should be able to create the target anywhere. So, you could create /var/websites/[domain] and then create a symlink in Drupal's sites folder that points from $drupalroot/sites/[domain].com -> /var/websites/[domain]

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 6 looks for a file named `settings.php` in a folder named `sites/mydomain.com`, or similar.  The exact rules are listed in default.settings.php.  If your host supports symbolic links, you could make mydomain.com into a link: the syntax is `ln -s /path/to/real/files/mydomain mydomain.com`

Drupal 7 is much nicer about how it handles multisite installs- it's possible to tell drupal where the settings.php file is for each domain.  There's a patch that backports this feature here:  http://drupal.org/node/231298